# Storing raw and processed data for efficient use in matplotlib

Tags: python, storage

I have some large data sets (numeric and textual) and as I'm studying and making visualizations with python and numpy/matplotlib, I'm running into a problem: I load the raw data, apply calculations, then create graphs in matplotlib.  This is all in one program, so I'm redundantly and inefficiently calculating the same data every time I want to tweak a graph legend or make my graphs otherwise more visually appealing.  I'm only working with a small sample of my data set and the script runs for 30 minutes at a time!

I know the solution is to run the calculations and store the output for use in a separate program; then use a different program to generate the actual graphs.  My problem is that I don't know how best to store the processed data between programs.  Should I make a .csv file, or are there some suitable structures that can store the data in (possibly) human-readable formats automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/moin), a wrapper for HDF5 libarary. It was designed for that sort of thing.

Comment: Those screen shots look similar to matplotlib tables.  Is pytables reusing that functionality?

Comment: They used matplotlib to plot those test results. It's not part of pytables itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would just pickle them. That's very simple, usually fast enough and (if you use the newer, binary protocols) also reasonably efficient in space. Make sure to use the highest available protocol:

```
import cPickle
with open("results.dat", "wb") as stream:
    cPickle.dump(data, stream, cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
...
with open("results.dat", "rb") as stream:
    data = cPickle.load(stream)
```